# Assistance with Optional Regex in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to parse out the software, version number, and installed on date from data that looks like this:

```
AXIS Media Control Embedded
AXIS Media Control 5.60 Redist  [installed on 2014/05/28]
Cisco WebEx Meetings
Adobe Flash Player 13 ActiveX  [version 13.0.0.214]
Adobe Flash Player 13 Plugin  [version 13.0.0.214]
Bullzip PDF Printer 9.3.0.1516  [version 9.3.0.1516]  [installed on 2014/05/12]
Security Management System (Client)  [version 7.0.1.0]  [installed on 2014/05/28]
Symmetry7500 Plugin  [version 1.3]  [installed on 2014/05/28]
Cross Match Transmission Manager  [version 3.8.9.0012]  [installed on 2014/05/08]
Cross Match Live Scan Management System  [version 8.4.5.0031]  [installed on 2014/05/08]
System Center Endpoint Protection  [version 4.7.214.0]  [installed on 2016/07/21]
Mozilla Firefox 50.0.2 (x86 en-US)  [version 50.0.2]
Mozilla Maintenance Service  [version 50.0.2]
```

The data I'm working will always start with the software name, and then could have both version number and installed on date, or one or the other, or neither.  If both are present though it'll always be version number followed by installed on date.

Here's the regex I have so far:

```
(.*?)  ((\[version .*\])  (\[installed on .*\])|(\[version .*\])|(\[installed on .*\]))
```

This works except when it's only the name of the software.  Various placement of the ? to mark the OR section of the regex hasn't worked.  What changes do I need to make to capture Items 1 and 3, along with everything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use an expression like this:

```
(.+?)(?:  \[version (.+?)\])?(?:  \[installed on (.+?)\])?$
```

This uses non-capturing groups for matching the optional parts and capturing groups with non-greedy matches to allow extracting the relevant information.

- `(.+?)`: Capturing group to extract the software name.
- `(?:  \[version (.+?)\])?`: Optional non-capturing group to match version information (if present) with a nested capturing group for extracting the version number.
- `(?:  \[installed on (.+?)\])?`: Optional non-capturing group to match install date information (if present) with a nested capturing group for extracting the date.
- `$`: Anchor the expression at the end of the string.

Example:

```
$file    = 'C:\path\to\software.txt'
$pattern = '(.+?)(?:  \[version (.+?)\])?(?:  \[installed on (.+?)\])?$'

Get-Content $file | Select-String $pattern | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    Name        = $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
    Version     = $_.Matches.Groups[2].Value
    InstalledOn = $_.Matches.Groups[3].Value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On [regex101.com](https://www.regex101.com/r/xRPmdy/1) I succesfully tried:

```
([^\[]*?) *((\[version .*\])  (\[installed on .*\])|(\[version .*\])|(\[installed on .*\]))
```

I suggest using named capture groups, otherwise the numbering might be odd.